# Ruby LoadError: cannot load such file -- tk

Tags: ruby, windows, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use tk in Ruby in Windows 10. I have installed ActiveTcl and Ruby 2.4 from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/. I am getting error as:

```
F:/Utilities/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- tk (LoadError)
    from F:/Utilities/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Also checked the same from irb command prompt but got following error :

```
F:/Utilities/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- tk (LoadError)
    from F:/Utilities/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Could you advise me on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is solved now .

I just included the `msys2` folder in path and then applied the following command .

```bash
gem install tk
```

This included the gem .

So what one has to follow is :

1. Install ActiveTCL
2. Install ruby installer . At end this will ask for Msys2 installation . Proceed as per menu option .
3. keep ActiveTcl\bin,Ruby\bin and msys2 folder in path .
4. run the command :

```
gem install tk
```

This will solve the problem.

Best Regards,
Sudeshna Bhattacharya